# Can a USB monitor be used during BIOS config?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, headless

I'm pessimistic but hoping I'm wrong: can one of those cheap USB monitors be used on a computer during BIOS config, or do they all need drivers to be running before they show you anything?

I've got a broken headless PC booting to the command line, and a friend offering a USB monitor, but I don't think it woould help.

Comment: what do you mean by headless PC? what is your configuration and why would you need a monitor on USB and not on a regular VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can one of those cheap USB monitors be used on a computer during BIOS
> config,

No, that will not work. BIOS expects a directly connected monitor and can't deal with an external monitor.

You may not need BIOS to work with your computer, so the USB monitor will work for that.

If you really need to start in BIOS, then you need to replace the existing broken monitor.